# Outlook VBA ignoring filter and deleting all appointments in shared calendar

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I have a piece of code that is supposed to find all appointments in a shared calendar between two dates and delete them. However, it ignores the filter and deletes all appointments in the calendar. Could someone take a look at this and give me some idea of what i'm missing please?

```
    Sub DeleteCal_Appts(sCalendarName As String, ap_dateStart As String, ap_startTime As String, ap_dateEnd As String, ap_endTime As String)
        Dim objAppointment As AppointmentItem
        Dim objAppointments As Items
        Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim objRecip As Recipient
        Dim sFilter As Object
        Dim dtStartTime As Date, dtEndTime As Date
        dtStartTime = CDate(ap_dateStart & " " & ap_startTime)
        dtEndTime = CDate(ap_dateEnd & " " & ap_endTime)
        Dim myOutApp As Object
        myOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        objNameSpace = myOutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        objRecip = objNameSpace.CreateRecipient(sCalendarName)
        objRecip.Resolve()

        'objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Unit 2 Peanut Delivery Calendar"), 9).Items
        objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objNameSpace.CreateRecipient(sCalendarName), 9).Items

        sFilter = "[Start] > '" & Format(dtStartTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' And [Start] < '" & Format(dtEndTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
        objAppointments.Sort("[Start]", False)
        MsgBox("Total Items at begin: " & objAppointments.Count)
        objAppointment = objAppointments.Find(sFilter)

        For i = objAppointments.Count To 1 Step -1
            objAppointment = objAppointments.Item(i)
            objAppointment.Delete()
        Next

        MsgBox("Total Items at finish: " & objAppointments.Count)
        objAppointment = Nothing
        objAppointments = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: "it ignores the filter" - No. The code iterates over the unfiltered `objAppointments`.  `Find` finds the first item that matches the filter; to get the next match, use FindNext.  Or retrieve a filtered collection using [Restrict method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) and iterated over that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TnTinMn got the answer to this. My only remaining stumbling block was for the date conversion from UK to US:

```
sFilter = "[Start] >= '" & (dtStartTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")) & "' AND [End] <= '" & (dtEndTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")) & "'"

        objAppointments.Sort("[Start]", False)
        
        itemsCalendar = objAppointments.Restrict(sFilter)
        
        For i = itemsCalendar.Count To 1 Step -1
            objAppointment = itemsCalendar.Item(i)
            objAppointment.Delete()
        Next
```